# Rearranging an equation to form the limit definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

I am following a proof which starts with the following inequalities:

$$S_{i}(v) \geq S_{i}(v+dv) + (-dv)P_{i}(v+dv)$$
$$S_{i}(v+dv) \geq S_{i}(v) + (dv)P_{i}(v)$$

From this, we rearrange to form:

$$P_{i}(v+dv) \geq \frac{S_{i}(v+dv) - S_{i}(v)}{dv} \geq P_{i}(v)$$

Taking limits as $dv \rightarrow 0 $, we get:
$$ \dfrac{dS_{i}}{dv_{i}} = P_{i}(v_{i}) $$
using the sandwich theorem and limit definition of derivative.

My question is regarding rearranging the first two inequalities to form the third inequality bounded by the two variables. In this case, we assume that $dv > 0$, as the signs do not change. If we assume $dv < 0$, the signs change directions, however after taking the limit we reach the same result.

But what about if $dv = 0$? Is the proof not considering this case? Or we just stating the derivative is not defined at $dv = 0$? Can you still say the derivative of $S$ wrt $v$ is $P_i(v)$? Both functions are assumed to be continuous so even if $dv = 0$, therefore the final statement is still correct?

Comment: That's the whole point of the definition of limit in $\epsilon-\delta$ terms. I guess that Leibniz would have said that $d\nu$ is "infinitesimal" but "not zero". Nowadays we say that $d\nu$ "tends to zero", but it is definitely not zero.

Comment: Incidentally, if you already know that $S$ is differentiable, you do not need to distinguish between $d\nu>0$ and $d\nu <0$. You already know that the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{S(\nu+h)-S(\nu)}{h}$$ exists, so you can approach $0$ in any way you want and just recover it. So you can safely assume that $<0d\nu\to0$, for example. You can even just take a sequence of numbers tending to $0$, such as $1/n$. (If you don't know a priori that $S$ is differentiable, then it's a different story).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a limit, you just look at the behavior of the expression as it approaches the limiting value.  The actual value of the expression at the limiting value is irrelevant for a limit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Paul. To form the third inequality, would you not have to assume that dv does not equal 0? Prior to taking the limits.

Comment: @AK, sure, but fortunately that is not an issue when taking a limit.